# Liferay6 : Jsr168Dispatcher Struts2 class

Tags: liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6  and Struts 2 , and assume that this is Liferay 6 is according to JSR 268 complaint

org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher

I have seen a  example  of Liferay6 and Struts2 on to net in  which the portlet.xml consists of this .

```xml
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>TestPortlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>TestPortlet</display-name>
    <portlet-class>org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher</portlet-class>
</portlet>
```

This example works fine , but still i want to know if we would misss any of the features ??

PLease tell me if this portlet.xml is valid as it specificies jsr 168 version of Struts classs ??

Or should we use jsr 268 struts2 Portlet class ??

Answer (score 0):

Use org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr286Dispatcher:

http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/struts2-plugins/struts2-portlet-plugin/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/portlet/dispatcher/Jsr286Dispatcher.html

It extends Jsr168Dispatcher with Portlet 2 (JSR286) specific features - resources serving, events handling etc.

Though if you don't need those you could stick with Jsr168Dispatcher - your web.xml would remain valid. It's just you would miss our JSR286 features.